# the meaning of "how can a man help marrying?"

Tags: sentence-meaning

> Joan, an orphan, he says, servant in a gentleman's house where he used
>   to visit; no people of her own, no marriage portion; he pitied her. A
>   whisper in a panelled room raises spirits from the fens, fetches the
>   dead: Cambridge twilights, damp seeping from the marshes and rush
>   lights burning in a bare swept room where an act of love takes place.
>   I could not help but marry her, Dr Cranmer says, and indeed, **how can a
>   man help marrying?** His college took away his fellowship, of course,
>   you cannot have married fellows.
>
> — Wolf Hall by Hilary Mantel

I just can't figure this sentence out. Could you paraphrase this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

He means that the state of marriage is irresistible to men, that they are drawn to it and cannot help (but) seek marriage.

Comment: so it's like "how can a man resist marrying"?

Comment: Yes, that's it. . . "How can he help but marry," but said a little differently.  Not "help marrying" as in "give assistance."